# @Autowired object initialization and scope

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

As far my knowledge @Autowired object is initialized when the application start and this is handled by spring and scope will depends on what we specify in bean.xml and @Autowired object are available right before they are used actually in the code.

My question is in below code I want that for every call to SAController class a new SuperAdminDetailsManager object should be created. So I configure scope = "prototype" is that correct so that for every call to controller a new SuperAdminDetailsManager  object will be created.

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class SAController {

@Autowired
private SuperAdminDetailsManager superAdminDetailsManager;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SAController.class);
private ApplicationContext context = null;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sadminlogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectLogin(ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute("superAdmin", new SuperAdmin());
    return "sa_login";
  }

    public void setSuperAdminDetailsManager(
        SuperAdminDetailsManager superAdminDetailsManager) {
    this.superAdminDetailsManager = superAdminDetailsManager;
   }

}
```

**beans.xml Configuration**

```
context =   new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
<bean id="superAdminManager" class="com.serviceimpl.SuperAdminDetailsManagerImpl" scope="prototype"></bean>
```

One more question when I can get the object using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext why do I need autowired

**Object using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**

```
superAdminDetailsManager = (SuperAdminDetailsManager )context.getBean("superAdminManager");
```

Comment: *Is that correct?*: try it, and see by yourself. Regarding your second question: the whole point of dependency **injection** is to replace dependency **lookup**, mainly to make the code testable.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for late reply. I tried with one and I am getting new object for scope prototype